# How to get paragraph breaks in a standalone document?

Tags: standalone, parskip

I have a bunch (1000+) of standalone tex-snippets that I use to build documents. I also want to be able to compile them separately. Problem with these standalone documents is that I can't get paragraph breaks to work. I want to set the parskip in a package.

I tried the solution from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144868/103166, but it clashes with calc-package that I also need with some of the documents. I wasn't able to comment because I don't have enough reputation, so I made new question.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100mm]{standalone}

%\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip} % This doesn't work
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}}% % This doesn't work either

\usepackage{calc}
%%This works if calc-package is not loaded but fails when it is.
\makeatletter
%\g@addto@macro{\@parboxrestore}{\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}% This would work
This here is a paragraph.

There should be a blank line between previous and this paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see the advantage of `standalone` here? Why not just using `article` or `book`, if there's some `\chapter` - related content

Comment: Some of the snippets are longer than standard a4 for example and I want to see them in a single page. I also use them for other purposes like generating html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set \parskip without using \setlength:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\@parboxrestore}{\parskip=\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This here is a paragraph.

There should be a blank line between previous and this paragraph.
\end{document}
```